# What does this Talmudic expression mean?

Tags: words, talmud-gemara, bava-kamma

The גמרא in בבא קמא on דף סב עמוד א׳ discusses a case where someone ״דבטש בכספתא.״

What does that expression mean? What's the שורש of דבטש?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The literal meaning of דבטש בכספתא is: *kicked the money-box* - as Rashi says in [Shavuos Daf 30b](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01010.html#HtmpReportNum0057_L2):

> **בטש**. בעט

And similarly in [Eiruvim 54a](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01323.html#HtmpReportNum0104_L2):

> **בטשה ביה**. בעטה בו

And in [Shabbos 116b](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00879.html#HtmpReportNum0229_L2):

> **אתא חמרא ובטשא**. דחפתו לארץ

So the שורש of דבטש is בטש - and I suspect it's Aramaic - and the ד means *that*, to give us *that kicked*.

כספתא is a money box, as Rashi says in [Bava Kama 62a](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01001.html#HtmpReportNum0120_L2):

> **בכספתא**. ארגז שמניחין בו כספים

See the  באר היטב  on Choshen Mishpat [סימן שפח - דין נזק נשבע ונוטל](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01977_part_39.html#HtmpReportNum0000_L2). He understands it as *knocked the money-box* out of his hands - but not directly into the water.

> דל''ת דוקא השליכו בידים למים אלא אפילו זרקו לארץ ומכח זריקתו נתגלגל ונפל למים או **שדחפו מיד חבירו וממילא נפל למים** כה''ג חייב והיינו דאמרינן בש''ס **דבטש בכספתא** כו'‏

Comment: amazing answer!

Comment: Awesome answer! Slight correction: According to R' Dovid Feinstein in his shiur this morning, a כספתא is a box, not money.

Comment: @Moshe - thanks for the clarification: I added it in.